# How to use local file instead of url in data-background-image in revealjs presentations?

Tags: background-image, reveal.js

I try to use a background image in a reveal.js presentation.

I can do it by using this

```
<section data-background-image="http://url-to-my-image/image.png" data-background-position="left" data-background-size="contain">
```

But if I would like to use local file, this one does not work :

```
<section data-background-image="./img/image.png" data-background-position="left" data-background-size="contain">
```

Is there a way to use the local image path ?

Answer (score 0):

The second line should work, it is the correct way to load a local image.